# How to block .git Folder serverwide on NGINX?

Tags: nginx, web-server, network-security

I have a question about blocking the .git folders server wide on a NGINX system.
At the moment I'm playing around a little with NGINX, I actually use Apache.
In Apache, it's actually no problem to block all requests to a .git folder server wide.
Is there any setting for NGINX as well? If so, where do I need to put it, or do I have to do that with every site hosted on the server?

Thanks a lot guys, have a great weekend.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to block all locations starting with a dot on any level, i.e. `.env`, `.git`, `.htaccess`, etc. and make it look like there is no such location at all instead of confirming its existence to potential attackers.

```
location ~ /\. {
    return 404;
}
```

Another option is `return 444;` which makes nginx not send anything, as if the server is not even responding.

Comment: In addition, if you have a domain name hosted with CloudFlare, using `return 444` may cause some pages of the website to be rendered differently from other pages, which will make the attacker realize that there is something special here.

Answer (score 0):

A `location` block like this should do what you want:

```
location /.git {
  deny all;
}
```

That will return a 403 response.